# IDataReader consumes memory so much for 20m records

Tags: c#

My code looks like this

```
using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (dr.Read()){
       for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++){
           //read a table of 50 columns and 20 millions of rows into an array string[] data
       }
       ListOfArrayOfStringData.Add(data);
   }
}
```

My program freezes the computer after 5 minutes of reading. 
I open MSSMS 2016 and insert the same query `"SELECT * FROM theSameTable_I_TriedToReadWithTheAboveCode"`, it takes only 7 minutes to finish displaying all the records and the total memory consumed is only around 500 MB as the max value seen in my TaskManager. That is very strange. MSSMS 2016 seems to be using some new magics, doesn't it?

Comment: You need to rethink the use case which requires you to load 20m rows in memory...

Comment: What do you want to do with this 2d jagged list of 20M x 50 strings after you return it?

Comment: What is your question?  How to prevent your application from freezing?  Or what techniques Management Studio might be employing to display that much data efficiently?  Are most/all of the 50 columns being returned as `string`, or are you converting/`.ToString()`ing them in your `for` loop?

Comment: the idea of `dr.Read()` is to handle records one-by-one in large result sets. You can get the same result (reading of all records) using the [DataTable.Load](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1081/how-to-fill-datatable-from-datareader-in-c-without-dataadapter) approach. However I believe that loading 20M rows will cause the same out of memory exception as your list. You can use stored procedure on SQL to reduce loading data volume.

Comment: I think I should rethink the way I work. My customers want to display 20m rows then I must have my application displayed 20m. I don't want to change their want into mine. This indicates my serious lack of knowledge about this, not yet to mention my average skills in testing and bug finding and fixing. MSSMS could already do it, so there must be a way or ways. :-)

Comment: @DaWei But your customer doesn't want to display 20 million rows _all at once on the same screen_, right?  Therefore, you don't need to load all 20 million rows at once.  Beyond telling you "Don't do that" this question is hard to answer because A) the vast majority of Stack Overflow users haven't seen Management Studio's source code, B) _nobody_ on Stack Overflow has seen (much of) your source code, and C) you don't specify what UI framework you're using.

Answer (score 4):

It's a totally different situation, when you read from a database from code and from the management studio. It's not really magic, it's just that the studio will not block while returning the rows.

When you want to load so many rows from a database, you should be using some kind of paging:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs

Get a number of rows, so some work on them, then take the next batch

This next row:

```
ListOfArrayOfStringData.Add(data);
```

Will require a huge amount of application memory to used if you get everything. The query might end, but the for loop alone will require a lot of time to complete, making your application freeze.

MsSql management studio is using threading, internal paging and much more to account for all these.